# patoolib библиотека

Tags: python

Как работает auto-py-to-exe с другими библиотеками, есть ли проблемы с взаимодействием отдельных библиотек.

---

Данная ошибка возникает только когда я выбираю в критериях "оконное приложение"
Консольное работает без ошибок

Comment: вручную соберите pyinstaller'om попробуйте

Comment: Покажите весь код вашего приложения и настройки в autopy